# How can I call jquery Ajax call to Pass a Value from Client Side to Asp.Net Code Behind (.cs) file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am creating a Web Application using CK Editor which is server side control.
I am not using any server side control expect CK Editor. 
I have Created HTML string using Jquery To display file names available on server with radio button . In radio button property i set property to store FilePath
.

```
<input type="radio" class="txtFilePath" idd="ArrayPar.FilePath"/>
```

When Change event executes I got Path Properly.
But now Problem is that I need the same Path in C# code behind File.

For that I have used in .aspx Page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnEmpName" runat="server" />
```

I set value of it using Jquery Like

```
$('#hdnEmpName]').val(vpath);
```

But When I click on button and In code behind 
I found Its value blank

```
string vPath = hdnEmpName.Value;
```

Please Help me proper solution for It.
How to pass dynamically pass jquery value to code behind file in c#?
Please give solution for external jquery.

Comment: use ajax to send data

Comment: [Ajax and WebMethod](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) This is what you need to do.